# Cannot load the Windows 8 SDK samples in visual studio?

Tags: directx, visual-studio-2012, winapi

I'm trying to load the directx samples which come with the windows 8 sdk samples.  At first VS2010 was telling me that the solutions where created with a newer version of visual studio so I installed VS2012 Express.  Now when I try to load up samples in VS2012 I get the following error and it won't load up the projects.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Gm2v.png

I'm trying to load the bump mapping sample but it happens on all of them, and that's not the directory I'm loading them from, I'm just loading them from the projects folder or the desktop.

Comment: I have the same problem, still trieng to figure out a solution. I thought it would be possible to use windows 8 sdk in vs2012 for desktop...

Comment: I gave up.  I actually just went back to the 2010 DX11 sdk, nothing in 11.1 I need anyway.

Comment: i did it! Check out this samples http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Direct3D-Tutorial-Win32-829979ef

Comment: Cool, thanks.  Not sure if I'll go back to the 8 sdk.

Answer (score 1):

You haven't stated which OS you are using, but I suspect the problem is that you are trying to load  a Windows Store app sample on VS 2012 installed on Windows 7. You have to have Windows 8.x to build Windows Store apps.

You can in fact use VS 2012 and the Windows 8.0 SDK (as well as VS 2013 and the Windows 8.1 SDK) to build for Win32 desktop. Keep a few things in mind:

- You need the VS 2012 or VS 2013 Express for Windows Desktop or higher edition (i.e. not the "for Windows" editions which only support Windows Store apps on Windows 8.x
- You need to set _WIN32_WINNT in your preprocessor defines to either 0x0601 (Windows 7 or later) or 0x0600 (Windows Vista or later). Otherwise, the application you build may be using APIs that are Windows 8.x or later. See [Using Windows Headers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383745%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)
- If you are using the legacy DirectX SDK with VS 2012/2013, you need to make sure you use the correct include/lib path order. See [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee663275.aspx).
- If you need Windows XP support, you can't use the Windows 8.0 SDK. When you use the "v110_xp" or "v120_xp" Platform Toolset setting in VS 2012/2013, you are actually using the Windows 7.1 SDK. When using the XP toolset, you have to use the old DirectX SDK. See this [blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/chuckw/archive/2012/11/26/visual-studio-2012-update-1.aspx) post.

Ideally you'd stop using the legacy DirectX SDK all together. You have a lot of options for that if you are using Direct3D 11 and targeting Windows Vista or later: [D3DX replacements](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/chuckw/archive/2013/08/21/living-without-d3dx.aspx), [Win32 desktop samples](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/chuckw/archive/2013/09/20/directx-sdk-samples-catalog.aspx), [DXUT](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/chuckw/archive/2013/09/14/dxut-for-win32-desktop-update.aspx) and [FX11](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/chuckw/archive/2012/10/24/effects-for-direct3d-11-update.aspx) updates, etc. The two places that require the legacy Direct SDK are XAudio2 on Windows Vista or Windows 7, and D3DX9.